# Redefine align environment with line numberig purpose

Tags: environments, line-numbering

Can I redefine `align` (and other math environments) to obtain something like my (dumb) example?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
Text
\begin{linenomath*}
\linenumbers[0]
\begin{align}
a+b&=  c+d \notag \\
&\quad +c+d \notag \\
&\quad +c+d \notag \\
&\quad +c+d \notag \\
&\quad +c+d \notag \\
&\quad +c+d \notag \\
&\quad +c+d \notag \\
&\quad +c+d \notag \\
&\quad +c+d \notag \\
&\quad +c+d \notag \\
&\quad +c+d \notag \\
&\quad +c+d \notag \\
&\quad +c+d \notag \\
&\quad +c+d \notag \\
&\quad +c+d \notag \\
&\quad +c+d \notag \\
&\quad +c+d \notag \\
&\quad +c+d \notag \\
&\quad +c+d \notag \\
&\quad +c+d \notag \\
&\quad +c+d \notag \\
&\quad +c+d
\end{align}
\end{linenomath*}
\end{document}
```

I mean that I'd like to obtain the same layout (equation's lines numbered starting from 1) for every aligned equation, without the need of inserting the `\begin{linenomath*}` etc. strings.

**EDIT.** I tried to use `xparse` to obtain my goal:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers

\usepackage{xparse}

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{align}{???}
       {\begin{linenomath*}\linenumbers[0]\begin{align}}
       {\end{align}\end{linenomath*}}
```

but I really didn't know what I was doing. I looked for an `align` environment definition in the `amsmath.sty` but I've not been able to find it (I'm not so good with LaTeX).

My question is: is it possible to redefine the `align` environment the way I'm asking for?

Comment: The manual mentions on p. 14 the mlineno extension, which can be found [here](https://www.lsc-group.phys.uwm.edu/bursts/papers/HFSdraft/mlineno.sty). Yet this seems only to affect the non-amsmath environments, but could be a starting point for redefining the latter.

Comment: @marmot I gave it a look but  I've not been able to apply it to the `align` environment. It's beyond my own knowledge of LaTeX.

Comment: Sorry to hear that but it is also far beyond mine. Of course, you could do something like `\newcommand{\beginnumberedalign}{\begin{linenomath*}\linenumbers[0]\begin{align}}` and and `\newcommand{\endnumberedalign}{ {\end{align}\end{linenomath*}}}` and perhaps even define your own environment using these.